# Age old question: What's the meaning of 'word'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

An old question, for which I could find absolutely NO reference on the internet for many years. Perhaps I wasn't looking in the right places, but I have no clue about its usage either.

Then I stumbled upon this article just now that actually happened to address the same premise. I tried to figure out myself as a function of context but my better judgement was to seek expert advice. So here goes.

In the following excerpt I found in [an article](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=valium&defid=1845831):

> Ricky: Yo player let me get some of that valium!
>   Albert: **** off these are for my back spasms.
>   Ricky: Okay fine then I will tell your girlfriend about last weekend.
>   Albert: Fine, here you go a**hole.
>   Ricky: Word.

What exactly does *word* mean at the end? What are its connotations? Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try looking it up at the same site?

Answer (score 0):

It is a form of agreement but if said sarcastically by Albert in this case, it could have had undertones  of disagreement.  Albert is demonstrably passive so his use of the term here is to reassure the more dominant Ricky, that he understands the outcome of their argument.  In short it should be understood that Albert is bending to Rick's will, or at most being passive aggressive.  Albert could have ended the same statement with "Yo" and produced the same result.